# I am trying to create a dynamic table. i want to get the number of rows equal to the number that user enters in the box

Tags: javascript

my problem is that i can not set an id for the input or a value. Because the input is inside JavaScript how can i call it ? and i want the values of the input change each time i enter a certain number.

i would like to see the values of the first column change, so if the user enter number four that means there are 4 lights.

```
function createTable() {
    var a;
    a = document.getElementById('number1').value;
    if (a == 2 || a == 1 || a < 0) {
        alert("Please enter a positive number greater than 2");
    } else {
        var rows = "<th>Light </th><th>Rating(W)</th><th>Span-from prev.light-(m)</th><th>Voltage Drop (v)</th><th>Voltage Drop( % ) </th>";
        for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            rows += "<tr><td><input type='number' id=frt  name='" + "Light".concat(i + 1) + "' id=li></td><td><input type='number' value=250 name='" + "Rating(W)".concat(i + 1) + "'><td><input type='number' value=40 name='" + "Span-from prev.light-(m)".concat(i + 1) + "'></td><td><input type='number' name='" + "Voltage Drop (v)".concat(i + 1) + "'></td><td id='amt'><input type='number' id='sum' onkeyup='myfunction(this.value);' name = '" + "Voltage Drop(%)".concat(i + 1) + "'> </td></tr >";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = rows;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" id="table" style="font: 20px solid bold;font-weight: bold; background-color:#707B7C;color:black;"></table>
    <input type="number" name="Numbers of Lights" id="number1" oninput="createTable()" value="3" style="width:40px; position: absolute; 
      top:300px; left:800px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Contain the input in a form and use onSubmit rather than oninput.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is, but I THINK what your looking for is `appendChild(node)` so that you don't reprint all of the rows every time a new number is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If change the line to this

```
 rows += "<tr><td><input value='" + (i  + 1) + "'  type='number' id=frt  name='" + "Light".concat(i + 1) + "' id=li></td><td><input type='number' value=250 name='" + "Rating(W)".concat(i + 1) + "'><td><input type='number' value=40 name='" + "Span-from prev.light-(m)".concat(i + 1) + "'></td><td><input type='number' name='" + "Voltage Drop (v)".concat(i + 1) + "'></td><td id='amt'><input type='number' id='sum' onkeyup='myfunction(this.value);' name = '" + "Voltage Drop(%)".concat(i + 1) + "'> </td></tr >";
```

you can get the iteration as a value in the first column.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly  what i was looking for.

Comment: I have another question. can i add an id for each input to use it to update the value?as an example, i want to add value to the last column which is          
          value='" + ((a-i)*1.04*z.value*40/2400)+  "'                                                                                
    so i want to add the value of the previous row to the next row and so on.

Comment: Of course. I would do something like `id="firstInput_${i}"` .. or if you don't like string concatenation `id='firstinput_ " + i  + "'`.. That will only work once the innerHTML is set though. If you need the value before, I would recommend storing your calculation in a variable then using it in the next calculation.

Comment: Last question. one of the values that it must be in the equation is the span value, which is an input that the user should enter it. if the table was made in html it will be easy to just get the value by "id.value", but in this situation i do not know how to get it.

Comment: You will probably have to setup a function to do the calculation, but you can always run functions directly from inputs using the attribute `onchange="calcFunction(this.value)"`. It all depends on your situation though. ID is possible as well just use my example from above on that input.

Comment: for the calculation part i sorted the equation in a variable                                          `P +=Math.round(((a-i)*1.04*z.value*40/1200)*1000)/1000 ; `                             
`value ='" + (P)+  "'`  and it did work. but my question is ca i make something like `firstinput_ " + i + "'.value` to put it in the equation?

Comment: Can I ask another question ? when ever I try to call    
    document.getElementById(`second_input_${i}`).value= anynumber;                          Inside the    equationP(i)   it says that i can not set the property of a null?.

Comment: Hmm, check typos on the input element.